# python 3 csv file - attribute error

Tags: python

I am trying to read in the following csv file:

https://github.com/eljefe6a/nfldata/blob/master/stadiums.csv

I copied and pasted the contents it into excel and save it as a csv file because it is in a unix format.

and I get the following attribute error message

Any help appreciated.  Thank you.

```
import sys
import csv
with open('stadium.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
      readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
      for line in readCSV:
          line = line.strip()
          unpacked = line.split(",")
          stadium, capacity, expanded, location, surface, turf, team, opened, weather, roof, elevation = line.split(",")
          results = [turf, "1"]
          print("\t".join(results))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/mapper.py", line 31, in <module>
    line = line.strip()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Comment: I donno why you split again `line.split(",")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using `csv` module, with delimiter as `','` and when you do -

```
for line in readCSV:
```

line is actually each row in the csv, and the row would be a **list** of all elements in that row, delimited by `','` . You actually do not need to strip or split them again.

You can try -

```
import sys
import csv
with open('stadium.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for line in readCSV:
        stadium, capacity, expanded, location, surface, turf, team,opened, weather, roof, elevation = line
        results = [turf, "1"]
        print("\t".join(results))
```

Please do make sure that the elements you do unpacking are there in the csv.

Comment: Thanks.  I just added in the elements and they are the column names with the first letter in upper case.  I am now getting this error message:                                              Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/mapper.py", line 30, in <module>
    Stadium, Capacity, Expanded, Location, Surface, Turf, Team,Opened, Weather, Roof, Elevation
NameError: name 'Stadium' is not defined

Comment: I forgot to enclosed them in quotes, so it works now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you call .strip() on line it doesn't work because line is a list type object. Strip is method that only applies to strings. If I'm correct about what you're trying to do the correct way to unpack the variables would be:

```
stadium, capacity, expanded, location, surface, turf, team, opened, weather, roof, elevation = line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3], line[4], line[5], line[6], line[7], line[8], line[9], line[10]
```

The above works because you put the location of the value in the list (line) within the brackets and unpack the values into their respective variables.
Then call you can do:

```
stadium.split()
```

for example.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV reader already separates all the fields for you. That is, your `line` variable is already a list, not a string, so there's nothing to strip and nothing to split. Use `line` the way you intended to use `unpacked`.

That's why you're using the `csv` package in the first place, remember.